# Ignoring ffi-1.15.5 because its extensions are not built

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, mobile, cocoapods

When I tried to install pod I m encountering this problem .

Ignoring ffi-1.15.5 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine ffi --version 1.15.5
Adding a custom script phase for Pod RNFBApp: [RNFB] Core Configuration
Auto-linking React Native modules for target `shipentegra`: RNCAsyncStorage, RNCClipboard, RNCMaskedView, RNCPushNotificationIOS, RNFBApp, RNFBMessaging, RNFS, RNFileViewer, RNGestureHandler, RNPermissions, RNReanimated, RNScreens, RNVectorIcons, ReactNativeLocalization, react-native-blob-util, react-native-camera, react-native-date-picker, react-native-document-picker, react-native-insta-story, react-native-netinfo, react-native-pager-view, react-native-restart, react-native-safe-area-context, react-native-simple-toast, and react-native-webview
[Codegen] Generating ./build/generated/ios/React-Codegen.podspec.json
Analyzing dependencies
[Codegen] Found FBReactNativeSpec
/Users/ekrembulut/Downloads/shipentegra-3/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods_utils/script_phases.rb:51: warning: Passing safe_level with the 2nd argument of ERB.new is deprecated. Do not use it, and specify other arguments as keyword arguments.
/Users/ekrembulut/Downloads/shipentegra-3/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods_utils/script_phases.rb:51: warning: Passing trim_mode with the 3rd argument of ERB.new is deprecated. Use keyword argument like ERB.new(str, trim_mode: ...) instead.
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "RCT-Folly":
In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
RCT-Folly (from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`)

In Podfile:
RCT-Folly (from `../node_modules/react-native/third-party-podspecs/RCT-Folly.podspec`)

It seems like you've changed the version of the dependency `RCT-Folly` and it differs from the version stored in `Pods/Local Podspecs`.
You should run `pod update RCT-Folly --no-repo-update` to apply changes made locally.

[!] use_flipper is deprecated, use the flipper_configuration option in the use_react_native function